# Extending Rails flash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, monkeypatching, extending, flash-message

I have in *app/lib/action_dispatch/flash/flash_hash.rb* file this code:

```
class ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash
  def my_method
    #...
  end
end
```

but when I call it in controller, I get *undefined method 'my_method' for ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x007fcf8e81e510:*

```
def index
  flash.my_method
end
```

Why? Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Try to define it as `def self.my_method end`. Also, you may want to inherit your own class from `ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash`.

Comment: I tried a class method - for sure, but it didn't help. Of course it didn't, flash in controller is an instance object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to require the file on startup, try using an initializer:

```
# config/initializers/flash_monkeypatch.rb

require "#{Rails.root}/lib/action_dispatch/flash/flash_hash"
```

And restart your app.

Comment: But my file is inside *app* directory. All files inside *app* directory should be autoloaded, right? I have moved my *lib* folder to *app/lib* to not bother with autoloading. So this is not the case.

Comment: well, but it did help, when moved back to */lib*. Don't get it. But thanks

Comment: Autoloaded is not the same thing as requiring everything in `/app` on startup. Autoloaded means that rails will automatically load the file when you reference a missing constant.